# How to create this layout using CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, semantic-ui

I am trying to get this layout using CSS but the most close implementation to get it is from pinterest.com but they need some Javascript for actually get the layout. I need to know if I can do it without use Javascript for calculate the position of the next item.

[image: **Layout**]

Comment: Post related code is a start.

Comment: have a google for jquery masonry, I think that will do what you are after

Comment: Take a look [at this](http://sickdesigner.com/masonry-css-getting-awesome-with-css3/)

Comment: With fixed width and height, this is very easy.

Comment: Masonary is what you are looking for

Comment: Why so many down votes? This is a legit question.

Comment: The question doesn't show any work on the part of the OP, it doesn't ask a specific question about a specific problem and any answers would be purely opinion based, hence the downvotes.

Comment: You could probably do something with `flexbox` https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Is it acceptable to change the source order of divs (1,3,5,2,4,6)?

Comment: @AlexChar you dont need code for this because I am asking how to created it.

Comment: @Pete I know how to created with Javascript but I dont want to use JS if I can avoid it but thank you very much for the reference.

Comment: @Scott I can't understand how someone can downvote to some question.

Comment: @APAD1 Did you read the description? Maybe is my English issue. I don't know how you could downvote when this can be your next problem ;). The people from Pinterest implemented so it's specific problem with actual use in the real world so I really don't understand your comment.

Comment: @SalmanA the order doesn't matter the real problem is put the next tag closest in the Y axis to the previous tag.

Comment: @YordisPrietoLazo I posted an answer but its browser support is limited.

Comment: @Moob flexbox doesn't work :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [CSS3 multi-column layouts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_multi-column_layouts). The content is distributed inside columns like a newspaper. Browsers distribute content so that all columns are same(ish) height. ***However note that (i) the content displays from top to bottom, left to right (ii) [the browser support is limited at the moment](http://caniuse.com/#feat=multicolumn).***

```js
$("#button1").on("click", function() {
  $("#container > div").height(function() {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * 300);
  });
});
```

```css
#container {
  -webkit-column-count: 3;
  -moz-column-count: 3;
  column-count: 3;
  -webkit-column-gap: 1em;
  -moz-column-gap: 1em;
  column-gap: 1em;
}
#container > div {
  -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
  page-break-inside: avoid;
  break-inside: avoid;
  min-height: 100px;
  border-bottom: 1em solid white;
  background-color: powderblue;
}
#button1 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
</div>
<input id="button1" type="button" value="Randomize box sizes">
```

Regarding screen sizes: you can use CSS media queries to control the number of columns. For example you could choose to show 4 columns on 1000px+, 3 columns on 800px+ and two columns on smaller screens.

Comment: You are the one, you are the one! Thank you very much sir. I got the limitation side but this is a very very good implementation. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

You just need to have three floating containers, like this:

HTML:

```
<div class="container"></div>
<div class="container"></div>
<div class="container"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.container { float: left; width: 30%; }
```

and then add your content, strechted to 100% width.

```
<div class="container">
   <div>1</div>
   <div>4</div>
</div>
<div class="container"></div>
<div class="container"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.container > div { width: 100%; }
```

That's just the simple idea, but if you try you'll get your desired results.

Comment: I assume `<div>1</div><div>2</div>` is actually `<div>1</div><div>4</div>`

Comment: @Curt You're right! Didn't pay attention to the actual numbers.

Comment: the problem is I think OPs html will have all the divs (1 to 6) as siblings, if they were able to split it into containers like this there probably wouldn't be a question about this, but that would also be a complete guess as no code has been provided so you may be correct

Comment: This changes source order (1,4, 2, 5, 3, 6). It that is not an issue then a better solution would be to use CSS column layout.

Comment: @SalmanA You're right, too! But I guess it's not that easy to achieve with CSS columns, although it would be better.

Comment: @Doodlebunch I got the idea and make sense but the problem is I don't know how many columns will be because depend of how much space do you have and the HTML is generated in the backend so I don't have too much control about the size of the screen.